# Face temperature detection without thermal camera ( by cellphone for Covid19)

Tags: image-processing

i like to know what method exist in image processing to have accurate temperature estimation of human body ( especially human face ) without tomography or thermal camera, so i asked about it at [Physic SE site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546157/face-temperature-calculation-of-captured-image-by-cellphone-camera-without-any), but because of being none clear the range of digital image pressing of temperature estimation which could be used for this propose and the technical details which it could need, i asked the software part of that question here.

SO what  image processing technique do you  know which could be applied for this propose?

Thanks.

Comment: hm, a camera senses visible light. Unless you're > 400°C, you're not visibly glowing. So, no, there's no accurate temperature sensing with a visible light camera. Not quite sure how you're hoping to achieve this? You've got a sensor for X, but want to measure Y, but Y has no influence on X.

Comment: I've left this question closed.  The question does seem to be more physics-oriented, but as you point out the (longer form) question on the Physics.SE site has been closed. As @MarcusMüller points out, temperature information is usually available in the IR band, but most cameras specifically mask out this band because the underlying electronics can be more sensitive to IR than to visible light.  [That's why thermal cameras exist.](https://www.wired.com/story/can-an-infrared-camera-detect-a-fever/)